# Search for text in PDF file using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, search, text-extraction

What is the best (i.e fast and optimized) way to search for text in PDF file using PHP ?

Also I have seen lots of libraries but again I don't know which library works the best for searching text in PDF.

Comment: I would suggest starting with https://pdfparser.org/. Try it out. If you have something workable but still encounter issues - get back to ask a more detailed question.

Comment: @Aleksander Wons Thanks a lot for your help. I will definitely try pdf parser to check how it works